# Compound Poisson Distributions: When, Why, and How To Split the Problem

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, multilevel-analysis, gamma-distribution, tweedie-distribution

I've just stumbled upon the Compound Poisson Distribution (CPD) and it seems to be precisely what I need.  For the purposes of this post, let's suppose I have a store that sells many items of different cost (often at a bit of a discount) and I want to be able to model the total daily revenue.  In fact let's say I have 10000 such stores, which to varying degrees have quite a lot in common.

One reasonable approach to dealing with this problem would be two separately fit multi-level models to predict number of sales per day (Poisson) and average revenue per sale (Gamma or Normal (is Normal really uncommon to use with a CPD?)).  This would have the advantage of separately selecting relevant features and perhaps slightly easier goodness of fit analysis.

Another reasonable approach would be to directly fit a CPD to my total daily revenue.  I feel like in this scenario, I can more accurately enforce any objectives I have as opposed to trying to factor those objectives; after all at the end of the day I care about accurately predicting revenue.  I don't want one day where I sell a million cow tails for little revenue to have an incredible effect on the model.

In addition to a response, any resources on CPDs, especially pertaining to multilevel models and the impacts of various underlying "weight" distributions, would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a lot.

P.S. @whuber, haven't seen you since my days in the problem solving group.  Hope all is going well.  Thanks for your insightful comments here.

Comment: I stopped in my tracks when I saw your moniker!  Welcome to our site.  I don't want to abuse my moderator powers by looking up your e-mail address for private purposes, but you probably still have mine--it hasn't changed in 18 years--so please feel free to get in touch offline.  It would be nice to catch up.